# The kernel use which scheduling algorithm?

Tags: process, schedule

I know there are a lot of scheduling algorithm for processor. like [FCFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-come,_first-served) ( first come first served ) Or [SJF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next) (short job first) and so on. How to know the kernel using which algorithm ?

Comment: if you have not modified it it is probably using cfq (completely fair queuing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Neither:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Since_Linux_2.6.23)

> ### Since Linux 2.6.23
>
> Con Kolivas's work, most significantly his implementation of "fair scheduling" named "Rotating Staircase Deadline", inspired Ingo Molnár to develop the Completely Fair Scheduler as a replacement for the earlier `O(1)` scheduler, crediting Kolivas in his announcement.
>
> The [Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) uses a well-studied, classic scheduling algorithm called fair queuing originally invented for packet networks. Fair queuing had been previously applied to CPU scheduling under the name stride scheduling.
>
> The fair queuing CFS scheduler has a scheduling complexity of `O(log N)`, where N is the number of tasks in the runqueue. Choosing a task can be done in constant time, but reinserting a task after it has run requires `O(log N)` operations, because the run queue is implemented as a red-black tree.
>
> CFS is the first implementation of a fair queuing process scheduler widely used in a general-purpose operating system.

If you're willing to look at the source code, [`sched/fair.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c) implements CFS, and [`sched/rt.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/rt.c) implements the [POSIX-required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realtime.html) FIFO (or what you'd call FCFS) and Round-Robin (RR) algorithms for realtime processes.

Further reading:

1. [Kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt)
2. [IBM developerWorks article on CFS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/)
3. [Linux Journal article on CFS](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/completely-fair-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

default kernel scheduler (CFS or EEVDF) and https://www.phoronix.com/news/Rust-Linux-Scheduler-Experiment